# iPhone 4 OS 5.1 JQuery + Position Fixed

Tags: php, jquery, viewport, iphone-4

I seem to be having a weird problem w/ only the iPhone 4 on OS 5.  This problem doesn't happen on the 4S or the iPhone 5.

I'm setting a nav bar at the bottom of my page that has a background with a sprite.  I'm then placing 3 individual divs on top of that nav bar so I can bind the click action and perform some sort of request.

I'm setting the viewport like so:

```
<meta name='viewport' id='viewport' content='width=device-width,user-scalable=no' />
```

And it might be worth noting that when the page loads, it loads like everything is zoomed in but once all the content is loaded, it's zoomed out properly and everything fits on one page.

HTML:

`<div id='footerNav' style='position: fixed; bottom: 0;'>`

```
<div id='cell1'></div>
<div id='cell2'><div>
<div id='cell3'></div>
```

`</div>`

Javascript:

```
jQuery('#footerNav').delegate('#cell1', 'click', function() { alert('click'); });
jQuery('#footerNav').delegate('#cell2', ....);
jQuery('#footerNav').delegate('#cell3', ....);
```

Now this renders the the footer with the background image and the 3 divs fine and everything at the bottom of the page (I placed a border: 1px solid red in the css to make sure it was showing up where it was suppose to).  The weird problem is the clickable area is now above the footer.

And even more weird is that if you were to rotate the iPhone landscape and then back, the touchable area works as it's suppose to.

I have a feeling it has something to do w/ how Safari deals w/ the viewport when it zooms out to fit the content but I can't really prove it.  I'm hoping for any insight on this problem.

Thanks in advance!